# How to delete records in table where are empty spaces when using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

I want SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer() ignore empty spaces. It already ignores NULL and duplicate values but now I want it to ignore empty spaces:

First made connection:

```
private void connection()    
{
    sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCom"].ConnectionString;    
    con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn); 
}
```

Then I insert records from a CSV file into the SQL Server table:

```
private void InsertCSVRecords(DataTable csvdt)  
{
    connection();  

    // creating object of SqlBulkCopy    
    SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);  

    // assigning destination table name    
    objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Users";  

    // Mapping the table columns
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");  
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");  
   
    // inserting rows into database    
    con.Open();  
    objbulk.WriteToServer(csvdt);  
    con.Close();  
}
```

Extract text from CSV:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    DataTable tblcsv = new DataTable();  
    //creating columns  
    tblcsv.Columns.Add("Name");  
    tblcsv.Columns.Add("Email");  
   
    string CSVFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  
      
    string ReadCSV = File.ReadAllText(CSVFilePath);  
    
    foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))  
    {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))  
        {  
            //Adding each row into datatable  
            tblcsv.Rows.Add();  
            int count = 0;  

            foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(','))  
            {  
                tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;  
                count++;  
            }  
        }    
    }  

 /////// delete NULL records////
 tblcsv = tblcsv.DefaultView.ToTable(true, Name.Trim(), Email.Trim());


            for (int i = tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                tblcsv.Rows[i][2] = "1";
                ////2.) null values
                if (tblcsv.Rows[i][0] == DBNull.Value || tblcsv.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    tblcsv.Rows[i].Delete();
                }    
                
            }
            tblcsv.AcceptChanges();

   
    InsertCSVRecords(tblcsv);  
}
```

I tried to delete NULL/duplicate values which works but can`t delete empty space records what to do?

Comment: Why don't you just not add the row, rather than adding then deleting? Also `con` should go in a `using`, and not stored in a field.

Answer (score 0):

Try checks using `string.Empty` or `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` or `DBNull.Value.ToString()`